# hello.js not in AngularJS web app not working on iPhones and Blackberry Z10s

Tags: iphone, angularjs, blackberry, hello.js

I have a login system that works for most people (on Chrome, Android devices, IE8, Firefox, etc), but it seems not to work for people with Z10s or iPhone 5s.  I don't have access to these devices so it's difficult to test, so I wanted to ask whether I was setting up everything properly.

It's an AngularJS app, using hello.js for OAuth, and bootstrap-social and font-awesome for the sign in buttons.

To insert hello into Angular, in `app.js` I include:

```
var app = angular
.module('myapp', [
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.router',
'hello',
])
...
.run([..., 'hello', ..., function(..., hello, ...) {
   ...
   hello.init(...);
   ...
}]);
...

var helloApp = angular.module('hello', []);
helloApp.factory('hello', function() {
    return window.hello; // Assumes hello has been loaded
});
```

Then, in my `loginCtrl`, I inject it with

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('loginCtrl', [..., 'hello', ...,
function(..., hello, $location, ...) {

...

$scope.doLogin = function(network) {
    console.log('Calling hello ' + network);
    hello.login(network);
};

...
}]);
```

And in my view, I have

```
        <button id="facebookLogin" class="btn btn-social btn-facebook" ng-click="doLogin('facebook')">
            <span class="fa fa-facebook pull-left"></span> <span>Sign in with Facebook</span>
        </button>
        <button id="googleLogin" class="btn btn-social btn-google-plus" ng-click="doLogin('google')">
            <span class="fa fa-google-plus pull-left"></span> <span>Sign in with Google</span>
        </button>
```

Yesterday I was using `onclick="hello.login('facebook')"`, and I suspected that was breaking on certain devices because I shouldn't be using `onclick` and `hello` wasn't in scope, so that's why I changed it to `ngClick` and calling a function in scope.  The specific effect of `onclick` on the users who had errors was to redirect the user to the default/catch-all route without accessing the server at all (I listen for hello events and call the server, so this suggests it wasn't calling hello at all.)

But still, I ask the people who are having issues to re-try (after refreshing obviously), and now they say the button simply does nothing.

Other buttons on the site work.  In fact, to get to this page, they use a `<button>` that uses `ui-router` to get to this page.

I'm going to continue to search, but I just wanted to ask if I seemed to be hooking hello.js into AngularJS properly, and not making any other beginner mistakes.

Comment: I've changed it to use "page" rather than "popup", and and now the issue is that it doesn't return properly.  Hello.js has it using a hash to mark the url fragment, while my app uses the hashbang

Comment: did you fix this, I have trouble with the return even on regular browser

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm still using my hack (where I use `display:'page'` for iPhones)  I've been overwhelmingly busy, but still intend on trying @Drew 's suggestion form the comments below.

Comment: Could you fix this using popups?

Comment: I think I was.. or did...  I haven't worked on this project in a year and a half now though :S  If I remember right, what really fixed it was waiting until spring 2015 and pulling in the new updates for hello.js. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that iPhones and Z10s were blocking hello.js's `popup` OAuth authentication, but I couldn't just switch it to use `page`.

When I tried, Facebook returns me to my `redirect_url` with the fragment

`#access_token=....&expires_in=4264&state={%22client_id%22%3A%22164986300332415%22%2C%22network%22%3A%22facebook%22%2C%22display%22%3A%22page%22%2C%22callback%22%3A%22_hellojs_3ojn1yy8%22%2C%22state%22%3A%22%22%2C%22oauth_proxy%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fauth-server.herokuapp.com%2Fproxy%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22basic%22%2C%22oauth%22%3A{%22version%22%3A2%2C%22auth%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%2F%22}}`

it's ugly, but the point is it starts with a hash tag.  So, while hello.js can normally read this, it couldn't in this case because Angular would mangle the address immediately.  I'm not sure if this is because I specify to use hash-bangs instead of hash's, but it was.

And I couldn't send this to a PHP script or anything because the fragment after the hashtag would never make it to the PHP script.

So, my solution was to point the `redirect_url` at an independent page that has hello.js on it, but no Angular.  It saves stuff to `window.sessionStorage` and redirects the user back to the login page, where hello.js passes the user through.

I'm not very confident in this ugly approach yet, so I put a browser sniffer to only do it for iPhones (and use `popup` for everyone else), I may remove this check in the future (because it's sketchy)

Answer (score 1):

@matt it uses localstorage, not sessionstorage.

Use popup for all, and define a redirect_uri page with just hello.js In it. I dont know why you might think thats sounds wrong. All the demos do it this way. It also gives you a chance to display a nifty loading screen.

Sorry about the ugly fragment. It communcates a lot of state  parameters which is used for the oauth proxy... most endpoints like facebook dont need it, so I might refactor that to make it a little less daunting.

Comment: Hmm, it's possible that I tried fixing two connected issues at once, i.e. changed to `display:page` AND created a hello.js-only redirect page, when the latter alone would have worked.  Before creating the page though, when iPhone users clicked the login button, they reported that nothing at all happened.  Anyways, I much prefer the login popup, and hate the browser sniffing I inserted, so this weekend I might be able to get my hands on an iPhone and experiment with `display:popup` and my new hello.js-only redirect page.  Thanks!

Comment: I have to confess I'm not that familiar with localstorage, when I said sessionStorage, what I meant is that my code in Angular grabs the token and stores it in sessionStorage.  I use this to login to my server.  Should I instead just grab the token right out of what hello.js stores in localStorage?

Comment: Probably best to get the session tokens by listening to changes, i.e... hello.on('auth.login', function(res){/* do something with res.authResponse */})

Comment: That's the listen I use to set the key in sessionStorage